# How to add a JavaScript listener to a PrimeFaces Ajax event

Tags: javascript, ajax, primefaces, listener

I want to listen pickList transfer event via javascript method,

Listener works well with java bean:

```
<p:pickList value="#{pickListBean.cities}" var="city" 
itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}">
<p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{pickListBean.handleTransfer}" />
</p:pickList>
```

But that doesn't work:

```
listener="myJavaScriptMethod(event)"
```

Are there any way listening events like above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

listener is serverside, in client you can use oncomplete, onsuccess,..(your option):

```
 <p:ajax event="transfer" oncomplete="js_function()" />
    <p:ajax event="transfer" onstart="js_function()" />
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, i have seen an example at documentation : 

    <p:pickList value="#{pickListBean.cities}" var="city" 
    itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}" onTransfer="handleTransfer(e)">